# Multidimensional associative array in asp

Tags: asp.net, arrays

I have been trying to find the awnser to this for a while. I am converting a site from php to asp. I have an array like this.

```
$students = array(

    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "John",
        "group" => "A"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "Joe",
        "group" => "A"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "3",
        "name" => "Derp",
        "group" => "B"
    ),
);

foreach($student as $slacker){
    //use the data
}
```

Is there any alternative that even comes close to this with asp?

Comment: You want to convert it to asp.net data structure?

Comment: Sure, anything that would let me use it in a similar way.

Comment: In c# array is different with php. Array is combination of index and value. The index is a numericla field. It is not like php where you can have anything in index. in your requirement you can use structure or class collection or array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a class and use generic list to hold the array of your class type.

```
public class YourGroup
{
   public string id { get; set; };
   public string name { get; set; };
   public string group { get; set; };       
}

List<YourGroup> lstGroup = new List<YourGroup>();
lstGroup.Add(new YourGroup(id ="1", name="Jon", group="A1"));
lstGroup.Add(new YourGroup(id ="2", name="Jon", group="A2"));
lstGroup.Add(new YourGroup(id ="3", name="Jon", group="A3"));
string idOfFirst lstGroup[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for what is called a dictionary. While its not quite deep nested like $myArray['foo']['bar'] the dictionary will allow you to stuff like

```
 Dictionary<int, MyObject> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
```

where your MyObject holds the following object

```
 class MyObject
 {
      public string name;
      public string group;
 }
```

as a result you can traverse it as such

```
MyObject foo = new MyObject();

foo.name = "tada!";
foo.group = "foo";

myDictionary.add(1, foo);

foreach (MyObject obj in Dictionary.Values)
{
     //Do Stuff
}
```

a completely string associated array would be

```
 Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 string something = myDictionary["value"];
```